# Get the elements that have children b or c

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing

Here is a sample of the XML I'm looking at:

```
    <m>
       <b name = "b1"></b>
       <c name = "c1"></c>
       <d name = "d1"></d>
    </m>
    <n>
       <b name = "b2"></b>
       <c name = "c2"></c>
    </n>
```

I would like to load all the elements that has children b or c .

Basically, the elements form  ".//b"  and elements from  ".//c"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query:

```
//*[b or c]
```

Comment: Which XPath version are you using? Or which programming language? (This might indicate the XPath version)

Comment: I am parsing an xml file in python using xml.etree which supports xpath queries.  The xpath version as indicated in the package is 1.0